# why ts file could not recognized on the sub project of mono repo

Tags: typescript, monorepo

I create d simple `example.ts` file like this:

```
const message: string = "Hello, TypeScript!";
console.log(message);
```

and use this command to compile the ts file:

```
npx ts-node example.ts
```

when I put the example.ts on the root of mono repo, it works. But when I put the file in the sub project of mono repo, shows error:

```
> npx ts-node example.ts
npm info using npm@9.6.7
npm info using node@v16.14.2
npm info found workspace root at ./ 
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for ./packages/lezer-tex/example.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:87:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:102:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:21:14)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:280:58)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:66:26)
    at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:297:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:261:34)
    at async Promise.all (index 0) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

why the ts file could not recognized in the sub projects? what should I do to avoid this issue? This is the mono repo structure:

```
root
  --packages
    --project A
      --package.json
      --tsconfig.json 
    --project B 
      --package.json
      --tsconfig.json
```

this is the sun project typescript config:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.build.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "tests", "third_party"]
}
```

I also tried to put the example.ts to the sub project's src folder. still could not be recognized.